# How can I set dynamically prepared query statement in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a jtable. I run data from mysql database. I use a query with prepared statement:

```
"select * from customer where city=? and region=? and price>?"
 pst.setString(1,"rome")
 pst.setstring(2,"italy")
 pst.setdouble(3,"1500")
```

my problem is that one time i need only one parameter (for example city).
i ask you i change every time a query o r i can set dynimicaly number of parameter??

Thanks

Comment: You'll need separate queries for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

(I think seperating them into seperate queries is a better solution, but if you want to do it this way, maybe something like this could help you)

I once wrote something like this

```
public ArrayList<User> searchUsers(HashMap userProperties)
{
    ArrayList<User> foundUsers = new ArrayList<User>();

    String searchString = "select * from chatusers where ";
    int addedProps = 0;
    if (userProperties.get("username") != null && !userProperties.get("username").equals(""))
    {
        searchString += "nickname like '%" + userProperties.get("username") + "%'";
        addedProps++;
    }
    if (userProperties.get("firstname") != null && !userProperties.get("firstname").equals(""))
    {
        if (addedProps > 0)
            searchString += " AND ";
        searchString += "voornaam like '%" + userProperties.get("firstname") + "%'";
        addedProps++;
    }
    if (userProperties.get("lastname") != null && !userProperties.get("lastname").equals(""))
    {
        if (addedProps > 0)
            searchString += " AND ";
        searchString += "naam like '%" + userProperties.get("lastname") + "%'";
    }
....
```

Of course you would have to change the "userProperties.get("prop"). to a "?" (I know I need to use preparedStatements, this was just for something silly at university before we had seen preparedStatements.

Furthermore I would go on in a similar fashion to actually bind the variables in the end. (keep track of where you added which variable, at which index, which you know because of the if-statement).

Comment: Building queries dynamically like this is a very bad idea and shouldn't be attempted unless there really is no better option.

Comment: I agree with you completely on that. I mentioned it at the start of my post, but it was a possibility if the OP would insist. ^^
But nevertheless, I wouldn't do it again ;-)